# Loop showing unwanted divs when going through categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m working with this loop in my `views/pages/index.html.erb`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <% @products.each do |category, products| %>
      <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block">
          <% if index == 0 %>
            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
            <div class="caption">
              <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
            </div> 
          <% end %>
        </div> 
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

it works fine and does what it is supposed to do which is to loop through each category and present the last picture added to each category.

But the problem is when I´m adding products and assigning them to categories in `views/products/new.html.erb`  the loop above seems to add extra empty `div's`to the row. I don´t understand why it is doing that... can anyone give me a hint why this is happening?

this is a screenshot how it appears in google dev tools
[image: screenshot]

As you can see there are four empty unwanted divs in the row.

Comment: I guess the   <% if index == 0 %> condition should be above the div , not underneath it , no ?

Comment: ehmmm.... yes that seems to have been the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not guaranteed but i think `if` condition is creating problem.

First check by removing `<% if index == 0 %>` condition, if it works fine, make necessary changes in it.